# HttpWebRequest : empty body

Tags: java, c#, spring, web-services, rest

I have some Java REST WS which are working well.
Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String filterByAttribute(@RequestBody final Constraint filterConstraint) {
RestConfigurationService.LOGGER.info("Calling rest service filterByAttribute with params [ attributeName: " + filterConstraint.getAttribute()
        + ", attributeValue: " + filterConstraint.getValue() + "]");
//...Some stuff....
    return "hello";
}
```

Constraint Pojo :

```
/*    */ @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
/*    */ public class Constraint
/*    */ {
/*    */   @JsonProperty("attribute")
/*    */   private String attribute;
/*    */   @JsonProperty("value")
/*    */   private String value;
...
```

I try to call that WS in my front C# webapp with this code :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(completeUrl);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{ \"attribute\": \"Applications\", \"value\": \"Pompes et appareils immergés\" }";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        string token = (string)Session["token"];
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);


        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
...
```

(I use OAuth, this part is OK.)
On the C# side I get an error 400 bad request.
On Java WS Side :

06-01-2016 09:27:46,141 [ramework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod:168 :DEBUG] http-bio-8080-exec-6 -  - **Error resolving argument [1] [type=java.lang.String]**
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.blabla.volta.rest.service.RestConfigurationService]
Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.blabla.volta.rest.service.RestConfigurationService.filterByAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: **Required request body is missing:** public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.blabla.volta.rest.service.RestConfigurationService.filterByAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:151)

What do i miss?

**Edit** : I've tried with

```
string json = "pwet";
```

and on java side i got

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

So i understand that my json (the first one) is not well formated or something, but java service actually see the msg.

Comment: I found solution, correct msg was :  string json = @"{ ""attribute"":  ""Applications"" , ""value"":  ""Pompes et appareils immergés"" }";